# How do I set up cron job for laravel project on hostinger?

Tags: laravel, cron

I tried setting up cron job on the 3rd of feb 2023 on hostinger and after sorting for the help online, they were not friutful, until I chatted chatgpt who assisted me throughout the way until I was able to solve the problem.
My goal is to document my solution here for future purpose by answering the question i have asked

I tried this and updated the code to my project path

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

and I created the cron job, yet no solution

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of trying to solve the above problem, chatgpt assisted in getting a solution. And this is a detailed work through.

log in to your hpanel and inside your public_html create a bash.sh file inside which u will put in this code

```
> #!/bin/bash

`export $(cat /path/to/your/project/.env | xargs)`
`#!/bin/sh /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/project/artisan schedule:run
```

`

e.g

```
#!/bin/bash

`export $(cat /home/u849535907/public_html/.env | xargs)`

`/usr/bin/php /home/u849535907/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`
```

when done save the bash.sh file

next go over to the cron tab on your hpanel, click on custom to create a custom cron job, paste this code inside of there

```
bash /path/to/your/bash/script.sh
```

in my case my path was
bash /home/u849535907/public_html/bash.sh
saved and run your cron job, you will notice the following errors

```
/home/u849535907/public_html/bash.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found 
/home/u849535907/public_html/bash.sh: line 4: 1 : ambiguous redirect
```

below is an explanation of the above error message and how to fix it
The error messages indicate that there are issues with the script file

> /home/u849535907/public_html/bash.sh.

The first error message

> /home/u849535907/public_html/bash.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found

suggests that the file has Windows line endings (CRLF), which are not supported in **Unix/Linux** systems like your hosting provider.

The second error message

> /home/u849535907/public_html/bash.sh: line 4: 1: ambiguous redirect

indicates that there's an issue with the syntax in `line 4`.

You can resolve these issues by converting the line endings of the file to **Unix line** endings (LF), and checking the syntax of the commands in the script.

To fix this simply download your bash.sh file from your hpanel, copy it to https://app.execeratics.com/LFandCRLFonline/?l=en this website will convert the file to unix style and your system will download it.

Finally rename the download file back to it original name, delete the bash.sh that already exist on the hpanel and upload this new file, that has same name.

Voola u are set to go,
you could also delete the existing cron job and redo it again and everthing we start working fine